# Webcam recording with JPEG CUDA codec in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, webcam, jpeg, cuda

Put simply, I have to capture a DirectShow webcam raw video as single JPEG images. I want to use NVIDIA GPU power for that.

As far as I know from the [FFmpeg hardware acceleration](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) and from [NVIDIAs FFmpeg site](https://developer.nvidia.com/ffmpeg), there is no built in support for JPEG CUDA encoding via FFmpeg.

I found some proprietary solutions from 'fastcompression' and 'norpix'.

But does anyone know free libraries/solutions for this approach?

If anyone has other groundbreaking ideas (also apart from FFmpeg), please let me know too :)

Comment: Does the webcam support MJPEG natively? Most all webcams I've used can provide MJPEG directly from the camera's hardware. If you want I can post a more detailed answer to get a bunch of images from the MJPEG stream.

Comment: @Hydranix it only provides uncompressed video  (YUYV422 from a Magewell, or NV12 from an Epiphan device)

Comment: How flexible is your output requirement? Does it absolutely have to be jpeg images, or could it be H264 encoded video? I'm familiar with using Nvidia's NVENC hardware encoding via ffmpeg.

Comment: @Hydranix unfortunately it must be frame based, so H264 is no option ..

Comment: Hello, in the meanwhile NVIDIA has released its nvJPEG library. Are there any plans to for an FFmpeg integration?
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvjpeg/index.html#title-nvjpeg-encode